# Conditions for an ODE with convolution term to have a probability distribution solution

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, fourier-transform

Suppose we have a simple ODE like:
$$
y''(x) + 2ay'(x) + by(x) = 0
$$
with the condition $y(0)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. Then the solution on $(0,\infty)$ will be of the form $Axe^{-ax}$ when $a^2=b$, $Ae^{-ax}\sinh(x\sqrt{a^2-b})$ when $a^2>b$, and $Ae^{-ax}\sin(x\sqrt{b-a^2})$ when $a^2<b$. So there is a solution to the ODE which is a probability density exactly when $a^2 \geq b$, since the first 2 solutions are integrable and everywhere positive.

If instead, we have an ODE with a convolution term, so:
$$
y''(x) + 2ay'(x)+by(x) + \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(u)y(x-u)du = 0
$$
where $f$ is an probability density function, and with the same conditions. Then can we derive an equivalent condition on $a,b,f$ which tells us when we have a solution which is a probability distribution function?

My approach so far has been to consider the Fourier transform to the equation which gives $-s^2\hat{y}(s)-y'(0)+2ais\hat{y}(s)+b\hat{y}+\hat{f}(s)\hat{y}(s)=0$ the Fourier transform of the solution as:
$$
\hat{y}(s) = \frac{y'(0)}{-s^2 + 2ais + b + \hat{f}(s)}
$$
My intuition is that I should now be applying Bochner's theorem, which states that $y$ is a density (or normalisable to one) when $\hat{y}(s)$ is positive definite. So is there so nice condition on $a,b,f$ (bearing in mind that $\hat{f}(s)$ should be positive definite, since it is the Fourier transform of a density) such that $\hat{y}(s)$ is positive definite.

Going back to the first example, we have $\hat{y}(s)=\frac{C}{((is)^2 + 2a(is) + b)} = \frac{C}{g(is)}$ (for some constant $C$) and a density solution (so therefore a positive definite Fourier transform of $y$?) exactly when $g(x)$ is not everywhere positive - which seems counterintuitive to me - but I conjecture that $\frac{C}{(is)^2 + 2a(is) + b + \hat{f}(-i(is))}$ is also positive definite when $x^2 + 2ax + b + \hat{f}(-ix)$ is not everywhere positive.

But I am not sure how to prove this or why this should be intuitively, or if this has already been proven anyway. Any ideas, pointers, or references would be greatly appreciated.